# How to communicate multi-form in Qt

Tags: qt, serial-port

I have a project on serial communications using Qt. This is very easy because I use `QSerialDevice`. The problem is making multiple forms to be accessed by `QSerialDevice`.

For example I have 2 forms, `form1` and `form2`. I try to send data over the last hyperterminal to be displayed in `form1` (done), but it cannot be displayed in `form2`. Not only that, but I want to be able to do `port->write` through `form2`.

My question is: can we use `QSerialDevice2.0` with multiple .cpp files and multiple forms?

Comment: Provide complete, compileable code example. Otherwise you're failing really to ask a question. We can't divine what your real problem is. Show us the code.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of QSerialDevice use better QtSerialPort http://qt-project.org/wiki/QtSerialPort

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell what you are looking to do is have 2 different UI forms that can be used to send data out a serial port. I am currently working on an almost identical problem for a project and what I have working for me is to use an [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) style architecture to solve the problem.

Have a controller that is knows which form is displayed and has access to the QSerialDevice. The forms can then emit a `void write(QByteArray)` signal, that would be connected to a slot on the controller responsible for writing to the port.

```
class Form1 : QWidget {
public:
  Form1();
  ~Form1();
  //some form1 stuff.
signals:
  void writeToPort(QByteArray);
}
class Form2 : QWidget {
public:
  Form2();
  ~Form2();
  //Do some form2 stuff
signals:
  void writeToPort(QByteArray);
}


class Controller : QObject {
 public:
   Controller();
   ~Controller();
 public slots:
   void writeRequested(QByteArray data);
 private:
   Form1* view;
   Form2* otherView;
   QSerialDevice* port;
 }


 Controller::Controller()
 {
    view = new Form1();
    connect(view, SIGNAL(writeToPort(QByteArray)),this,SLOT(writeRequested(QByteArray data)));
    otherView = new Form2();
    connect(otherView, SIGNAL(writeToPort(QByteArray)),this,SLOT(writeRequested(QByteArray data)));
    port = new QSerialDevice();
    port->open();
 }

Controller::writeRequested(QByteArray data)
{
   if (port && port->isOpen())
   {
      port->write(data);
   }
}
```

There can be other methods for dealing with the connection and switching between forms in the controller. By using the signals and slots there will be less coupling between the classes and you don't have to worry about serial port code clogging up your UI.